# Kafka : any script utility to change offset to a specific position?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 0.10 and I want to know if there is any tool (from those provided in the /bin directory) witch i can use to change the offset of a consumer to a **specific position** ?

I've seen that we can do from the Java API (with the *seek(...)* method) but i can't find a way to do it from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.11 is just out and added this reset functionality

You want to use kafka-consumer-groups command with --reset-offsets option